# Function Fields & Ring of regular functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, field-theory, elliptic-curves

From here - https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/elliptic/funcfield.html

> This leads us to define the ring of regular functions of $E$ to be

> $K[E] = K[X,Y]/\langle f\rangle$

> Its field of fractions $K(E)$ is called the field of rational functions of E

I find all the notations used here to be a little confusing.

1. When we say $E(K)$, it denotes an elliptic curve $E$ whose coordinates are in the field $K$ & when we say $E/L$ it means an elliptic curve $E$ whose equation coefficients are in $L$

I am struggling to understand here what $K[E]$ means as compared to say $E(K)$. The only thing I can think of is that this notation may be similar to $R[x]$ where $R$ is a ring of polynomials. So does $K[E]$ mean it's a ring of all elliptic curves? If so, what exactly is a ring of elliptic curves - how does a set of elliptic curves become a ring?

2. What is the meaning of the notation $K[X,Y]/\langle f\rangle$?

This notation usually means the ring of polynomials (of $X$,$Y$) quotiented by the ideal generated by $f$ - does it mean the same here?

3. What does "regular" mean in the phrase "ring of regular functions"?
4. What does field of fractions mean? What fractions are we talking about here?
5. What does "rational functions of $E$" mean here? I understand what is a ration function, but what is $E$ here - is $E$ a particular Elliptic Curve (i.e. defined by a particular equation)? Or is it some set of elliptic curves?

Comment: Yes $K[X,Y]/(f)$ is the quotient of the ring of polynomials in two variables by the principal ideal $(f)$. You can think to it as the ring of functions $E(\overline{K})\to \overline{K}$ given by polynomial expressions of the coordinates. We quotient by $(f)$ because $(x,y)\to x^3+ax+b$ and $(x,y) \to y^2$ are the same polynomial function on the elliptic curve $E:y^2=x^3+ax+b$.

Comment: $K[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3-aX-B)$ is the ring of regular functions on the (affine curve) $E$, also called the coordinate ring. Its fraction field is the field of functions given by rational expressions of the coordinates. Regular means given by rational functions of the coordinates but with no poles anywhere on the curve.

Comment: @reuns - thank you. Under who subject does this fall? I don't see function fields covered in most Abstract Algebra books or videos? Could you suggest a gentle introductory book for whatever subject this falls under? Would it be covered under Algebraic Geometry & even there many books don't seem to cover it

Comment: This is the first chapter in any text on affine varieties